# Integrate all the text boxes in one `KeyUp` event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex, textbox

I have four text box controls

```
txtEmpID
txtEmpSSN
txtZip
txtPhone
```

all the four text boxes allow only `numeric's`..

I have wrote the below code to achieve only numeric

```
$("#txtEmpSSN").keyup(function (event) {
  if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }    
});
```

I have wrote `KeyUp` event for every text box to achieve numeric
and my question now is..

Is it possible to integrate all the text boxes in one `KeyUp` event...?

Can any one help me on this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input").keyup(function (event) {
  if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }    
});
```

Or base it on a common class that you may put on the textboxes in question

```
$(".commonClassOnInputBoxes").keyup(function (event) {
  if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }    
});
```

Comment: you are right but i am not only having the four text boxes.. i have other textbox controls also so i cann't use this.. Can you give me another solution...?

Comment: Just put a common class on all the textboxes. Or list them out like in Arun P Johny's answer

Answer (score 2):

If you have many input fields, but want to bind only these textboxes for key up then use [multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#txtEmpSSN, #txtEmpID, #txtZip, #txtPhone").keyup(function (event) {
  if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer... It also worked... But I have used commonclass suggestion to solve my problem..

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this..

```
$("#txtEmpSSN, #txtEmpID,#txtZip,#txtPhone").keyup(function (event) {
  if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer... It also worked... But I have used commonclass suggestion to solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$("input[type='text']").keyup
```